# str_replace gerando erro Array to string conversion

Tags: php

Estou tentando alterar alguns caracteres demonstrados em array por espaço vazio mas o código me ocasiona o seguinte error:

> Array to string conversion

```
str_replace($string, array(',', '.'), '')
```

Não vejo erro, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que os argumentos estão na ordem errada, `$string` deve ser o último pois é a string a ser substituida.

O primeiro argumento `$serach` é qual(ais) caracteres devem ser encontrados, `$replace` é e pelo qual(ais) devem ser substituido e `$subject` é a string ou variável na qual deve ser feita o replace, `$count` é o número de susbtituições.

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

```
$string = '100,39';
echo str_replace(array(',', '.'), '', $string);
```